# how to reverse iterate over Queue?

Tags: c#

`foreach` loop iterates over `Queue` starting from the oldest item and ending with newest.
What if I need to start with newest and end with oldest (probably interrupting at some point as in most cases I just need to iterate over several newest items)?

i'm looking for straighforward and efficient solution. without recreating new objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use Linq's `Reverse()` function:

```
Queue myQueue;

foreach (var item in myQueue.Reverse())
{
    // do things
}
```

Comment: how expensive such function is?

Comment: @javapowered More expensive than a for loop. Normal `foreach` loops cost more than `for` but the difference is so small that I feel the better looking code is worth it.

Comment: Try it and find out ;) Linq queries are only evaluated when they're needed, so you won't really take a performance hit if you're only using the first few items, I think. @webnoob, does this sound right to you?

Comment: Using a straight forward foreach is still more expensive so it's not the Linq causing extra overhead, just the use of foreach (but again, more readable IMO).

Comment: @Fabian what `Reverse` exactly do? new queue created? `Queue` class already "double-linked" so it should be possible to iterate it in reverse direction without recreation, isn't it?

Comment: @javapowered google 'linq Reverse', have a read of this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx. Long story short: _nothing is recreated or modified_, just a pointer kept in memory.

Comment: Under the hood, Reverse() does a copy into an array held by an internal Enumerable.Buffer class. The iterator actually is an iterator on the Buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Both `Reverse()` and `ToArray()` have bad performance. If possible, change `Queue<T>` to `LinkedList<T>`.

LinkedList works like a deque (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue).

More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1

Answer (score 1):

`for` loop is your friend.

You have two option

- Reverse the order of the `Queue`
- Use `for` loop.

> ```
> for (int i = list.Length; i >= 0; i--)
> {
>
> }
> ```

Reverse the Order of the Queue.

```
Queue queue;

foreach (var item in queue.Reverse())
{

}
```

Comment: You just going to keep editing this with everyone elses answer in it? :)

Comment: what to use inside for loop? `ElementAt` method? how expensive this method is?

Comment: for loop is definitely more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop instead.

Edit: Added example of how to retrieve the item inside the loop.

Edit: Changed example to a `Queue` however I wouldn't know without checking if this is now more expensive that using `QueueList.Reverse()`

Reverse

```
for (int i = QueueList.Count; i >= 0; i--)
{
   var Item = QueueList.ToArray().ToList()[i] as SomeObject;
}
```

Normal

```
for (int i = 0; i < QueueList.Count; i++)
{
   var Item = QueueList.ToArray().ToList()[i] as SomeObject;
}
```

Comment: index can not be applied to Queue

Comment: @javapowered Post your code so I can modify my example to suit your needs.

Comment: why in your code you are operating with `List` while the question is about `Queue`?

Comment: I was just demonstrating an example of reversing through a list. Missed the `queue` reference.

Comment: @javapowered Updated my example which should work with a `queue`

Answer (score 0):

```
var newestItems = queue.Reverse().TakeWhile(item => IsNewest(item));
// if condition is simple, you can use lambda without creating named method
```

And later:

```
foreach(var item in newestItems)
    // do stuff
```

Readable, but expensive. In this case (when using `Reverse`) Linq will copy all items of queue into buffer.

*BTW* if you need to reverse order in queue, then consider to use `Stack` instead. It will be FILO queue type.

Comment: why simple things should be so complicated?

Comment: @javapowered because this makes them readable. Instead of reading **how** you do things I can just read **what** is done - `Reverse`. So, actually your for loop with decremented index is complex (fast, but complex).

Comment: i need perfomance and portability. i don't care about readability. pure c# should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @javapowered your question has tag `pure c#`. Portability of what? Copy c# code into java method?

Comment: i see. sure you code is an option. it just doesn't fit my needs

Comment: @javapowered btw what's the difference of my code with same performance expensive accepted solution? `TakeWhile` don't create copies.

Comment: probably it has the same perfomance. i don't know actually. also i can't say that your code is much more readable than "classic" version. I'm afraid it probably even less readable for some people :)

Comment: @javapowered do you understand that `queue.Reverse()` is the same as `myQueue.Reverse()` in accepted answer? Go and read some c# book :)